# Enqueueing common php scripts in a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, wp-enqueue-script

I have a plugin rejected by wordpress.org, one of the resasons is this:

> ### Unsafe Requiring of Common Libraries    Since you're using a common library, it's important that you enqueue it safely.    Example(s):
>
> require_once('jsonld.php');
>
> Since that is a common library, you need to detect IF the code is
>   already included and not re-include it, as doing so will cause
>   conflicts if two people call the same defines and functions.

I understand about enqueueing jQuery and CSS - but this is a PHP script with multiple functions.

1. If this script is common do I need to just reference it in the WP Core?
2. Otherwise do I need to just look at the functions I'm calling and wrap them in a class (I'm uncertain about this) or can I refer to the whole php script?
3. What is the standard way of doing this?

Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, it just means it's used by many plugins, not that Core includes it.
2. Many of the functions in that library seem to use the `JsonLdProcessor` class that is also in that library, I'd check for that before including:

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'JsonLdProcessor' ) ) {
    require_once( 'jsonld.php' )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check included files first.

```
$included_files = get_included_files();

if (!in_array("jsonld.php",$included files)) {

    require_once('jsonld.php');
}
```

Comment: `get_includes_files()` includes the whole path, so just checking the filename will probably return true, because *just* jsonld.php will not be included. `some/path/to/jsonld.php` would be. You'd need to loop through each file and check the filename. But I'm not sure I'd consider the filename a safe way to check. Better checking that actual code hasn't been loaded.